# How to access a CCMenuItemImage from a CCMenu

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCMenu that contains a CCMenuItemImage named pauseButton and a CCMenuItemImage named playButton. I need to be able to access the pauseButton and playButton, but once I add them to the CCMenu they disappear. I have set their tags and try to access them through [self getChildByTag:1], but the debugger says that nothing contains the tag. How can I access the members of the CCMenu?

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of your CCMenu variable?  If you code looks something like this:

```
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:playButton, pauseButton, nil];
```

Then you would access the play button or pause button with `[menu getChildByTag:1]` *not* `[self getChildByTag:1]`.  Otherwise, if you make a reference to `playButton` or `pauseButton` as a instance variable of the class or as a property, you should be able to access then directly, even if you add them to the menu.